# why fundamental Frequency and magnitude are not null when microphone is off?

Tags: qt, audio, fft, frequency, fftw

I would like to make real time audio processing with Qt and display the spectrum using FFTW3.

What I've done in steps:

I capture any sound from computer device and fill it into the buffer.
I assign sound samples to double array
I compute the fundamental frequency.
 when I'm display  the fundamental frequency and Magnetitude  when the microphone  is on but no signal(silence) , the fundamental frequency is not what I expected , the code   don't  always return zero , sometimes the code returns 1500Hz,2000hz as frequency 
and when the microphone is off (mute)  the code don't return  zero as fundamamental frequency  but  returns a number between 0 and 9000Hz. Any help woulbd be appreciated
  here is my code

```
  QByteArray *buffer;
 QAudioInput *audioInput;
 audioInput = new QAudioInput(format, this);

 //Check the number of samples in input buffer
  qint64 len = audioInput->bytesReady();

 //Limit sample size
 if(len > 4096)
 len = 4096;

 //Read sound samples from input device to buffer
 qint64 l = input->read(buffer.data(), len);
 int input_size= BufferSize;
 int output_size = input_size; //input_size/2+1;
  fftw_plan p3;
 double in[output_size];
  fftw_complex out[output_size];

 short *outdata = (short*)m_buffer.data();// assign sample into short array
 int data_size = size_t(outdata);
  int data_size1 = sizeof(outdata);

 int count = 0;
  double w = 0;

 for(int i(chanelNumber); i < output_size/2; i= i + 2) //fill array in
 {

w= 0.5 * (1 - cos(2*M_PI*i/output_size)); // Hann Windows 
double x = 0;
if(i < data_size){
    x = outdata[i];
}
if(count < output_size){
  in[count] = x;// fill Array In with sample from buffer 
  count++;
}
}

for(int i=count; i<output_size; i++){
in[i] = 0;
}
p3 = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(output_size, in, out, FFTW_ESTIMATE);// create Plan 
 fftw_execute(p3);// FFT
 for (int i = 0; i < (output_size/2); i++) {
 long peak=0;
 double Amplitudemax=0;
double r1 = out[i][0] * out[i][0];
double im1 = out[i][3] * out[i][4];
double t1 = r1 + im1;
//double t = 20*log(sqrt(t1));
double t = sqrt(t1)/(double)(output_size/2);
double f = (double)i*8000  / ((double)output_size/2);
   if(Magnitude > AmplitudeMax)
           {
               AmplitudeMax = Magnitude;
               Peak =2* i;
            }
 }

fftw_destroy_plan(p3);

 return Peak*(static_cast<double>(8000)/output_Size);
```

Comment: Instead of using a real signal, have you done any tests of "standard" signals in files (sin @ xHz)?

Comment: First of all is your silence true silence? i.e Is the audio Input filled with zeros when there is no input signal?

Comment: @KillaKem, when the microphone is off(mute) that means true silence  the audio Input filled with a lot of zeros  but its also filled with a big number like 4000, 6000 oder or number -1. I don't known where this big number come from

Comment: Where do you initialise `AmplitudeMax` and `Peak` ? Also note that for the sake of performance you should not keep creating and destroying your FFTW plan - it's an expensive operation and you should only do it once for a given FFT size.

Comment: @PaulR, I've edited the code, I initialise AmplitudeMax and Peak inside the second for iterations.each time when I call the function  peak , I create and destroy my FFTW,its that wrong? or what do means when u say I have to destroy and create once for a geiven FFT size?

Comment: Sorry - I was thrown off by the lack of formatting - I thought you were creating/destroying the plan inside a loop.

Answer (score 0):

What you think is silence might contain some small amount of noise.  The FFT of random noise will also appear random, and thus have a random magnitude peak.  But it is possible that noise might come from equipment or electronics in the environment (fans, flyback transformers, etc.), or the power supply to your ADC or mic, thus showing some frequency biases.

If the noise level is low enough, normally one checks the level of the magnitude peak, compares it against a threshold, and cuts off frequency estimation reporting below this threshold.

Comment: when the microphone is off(mute) that means true silence  the audio Input filled with a lot of zeros  but its also filled with a big number like 4000, 6000 oder or number -1. I don't known where this big number come from